# How do Krylov methods performance wise compare to direct methods when no preconditioning is done?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I know that when using Krylov methods we need to do some kind of preconditioning to ensure fast convergence. Lets say that I just don't do preconditioning, maybe because I don't know how to do it properly. I know that in this case the convergence will typically be very slow or to say the number of iterations will be close to the worst case number.

Is it still reasonable to use a not preconditioned Krylov method if all I care about is performance? In other words how does a not preconditioned Krylov method compare performance wise to direct methods via QR or SVD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Poorly. The fundamental problem is that Krylov subspace methods have low arithmetic intensity and are incompatible with modern computer architecture In contrast, modern implementations of the QR and SVD algorithms rely heavily on kernels that have high arithmetic intensity and are very compatible with modern computer architectures.

The key to answering the question is that to recognize that there is no restriction placed on $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, the right-hand side vector $b$, the Krylov subspace method and that you are prepared to execute $n$ iterations. We are therefore free to assume that the matrix $A$ is nonsymmetric and that we are done $n$ iterations of GMRES, i.e., the standard algorithm for this problem. The implication is that we have enough space to store the basis for the Krylov subsppace $K_n(A,b)$ and that $K_n(A,b) = \mathbb{R}^n$. In other words, we have enough storage to treat $A$ as a dense matrix! The cost of building the basis is $O(n^3)$. Why? We are doing a variant of the Gram-Schmidt algorithm. The cost applying GS to a set of $k$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is $O(nk^2)$. The cost of computing either a QR factorization or an SVD of a dense matrix is also $O(n^3)$. So, superficially, there is no reason to prefer one method over the other.

However, this is where it gets interesting. Modern computers have high flop rates, but the memory bandwidth is small and the latency is high. In order to achieve a significant fraction of the peak flop rate we must therefore use algorithms that do many arithmetic operations for every word retrieved from memory and reuse data in cache as many times as possible. Dense matrix matrix multiplication is the standard example of such a kernel. Say that we have two matrix $B$ and $C$ of dimension $m$, then $D=BC$ can be computed using $O(m^3)$ arithmetic operations and $O(m^2)$ memory operations. The arithmetic intensity, i.e., the average number of flops per memory operations is $O(m)$. As soon as the dimension is large enough, then the kernel will execute at high percentage of the peak flop rate. There is simply so much work to do, that it does not matter than the memory operations are slow. A significant portion of the work needed for a QR factorization or an SVD can be formulated in terms of this kernel. In contrast, even a sophisticated implementation of the GMRES algorithm will rely on operations that have low arithmetic intensity.

Krylov subspace methods are appropriate for very large sparse problems, provided that a good preconditioner can be found. They are fast, but they are not very efficient in terms of the hardware utilization. Achieving 10% of the peak flop rate is a significant achievement. In contrast, one should be able to do 80% of the peak flop rate for, say, Gaussian elimination of a dense matrix.

Comment: How hard is it to do preconditioning? In my lecture notes it is stated that finding a good preconditioner is not that easy in a sense that there is no generally good preconditioner. It seems to be for some part a creative process.

If preconditioning is actually hard, I could imagine most of the practitioners all over the world just using standard direct methods, am I right?

Comment: In general, it is very , very hard to do preconditioning. However, there are several classes of preconditioners that work very well for certain problems that are common in real world problems. Incomplete LU factorization, incomplete Cholesky factorization, approximate sparse inverse preconditioner and banded preconditioners are examples that are frequently successful. Direct methods have the advantage of having a deterministic runtime, whereas the runtime for iterative methods depends on the accuracy sought and is hard to determine in advance.

Comment: Do you know if Python or Matlab actually use krylov methods for their linear system solvers?

What would you say is a very large sparse problem and where does one encounter such big sparse linear systems?

Comment: @Josh.K You should develop this as a separate question as it is of interest to many others. It would be on topic at our sister site https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ First, do a search, because I would be surprised if something hasn't been written about this.